# Problems with vs2010 creating extra service contracts (appening a '1') in reference.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, service-reference

I am getting an error while compiling to my solution:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'MGApplicationModel.OrderProcessingService.OrderDetailSXe[]' to
>   'MGApplicationModel.OrderProcessingService.OrderDetailSXe1[]'

Both `MGApplicationModel.OrderProcessingService.OrderDetailSXe[]` and `'MGApplicationModel.OrderProcessingService.OrderDetailSXe1[]` appear in the `reference.cs` files but only `'MGApplicationModel.OrderProcessingService.OrderDetailSXe[]` should.

Anyone have a clue why whenever I update the service reference it would create `'MGApplicationModel.OrderProcessingService.OrderDetailSXe1[]`?  And the is no `'MGApplicationModel.OrderProcessingService.OrderDetailSXe1[]` anywhere in the solution besides `reference.cs`.

Answer (score 0):

Reference is your `proxy class`, and your proxy is generated by going from your `WSDL`, so you can adjust your `WSDL` with  definition